# Pára ou Para ? Conjugação do verbo parar precisa de acentuação?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico

Na frase :

> Quando você para para comer?

Preciso acentuar o verbo parar? Como diferencio o **para** do verbo parar do outro **para**?

Ficando assim : "Quando você **pára** para comer?"

Comment: Infelizmente, como muitas coisas do Novo Acordo Ortográfico na mina opinião, você só diferencia contextualizando mentalmente se o interlocutor se refere ao verbo **parar**, conjugado na 3ª. pessoa do singular, ou à preposição **para**

Answer (score 3):

Segundo [este artigo](http://www.flip.pt/language/en-US/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/4918) referido no dicionário [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/p%C3%A1ra) a grafia correcta pré acordo ortográfico era *pára* e passou a *para* pós acordo, ainda que segundo a discussão pareça ser incoerente e revelador de algumas inconsistências.

Comment: Precisaria citar exemplos, ou não?

Comment: Desculpe mas não percebi a sua pergunta. Precisaria de citar exemplos em que contexto?

Comment: 'Pare', forma verbal do imperativo, também se lia [páre] e já não levava acento gráfico antes do AO. Mas concordo que é muito estranho, mesmo para mim utilizador do AO. Até porque sempre o fizemos como nas palavras 'por' e 'pôr'. Por isso julgo que pára deve continuar a levar acentuação gráfica exatamente para fazer essa distinção. Para para pensar, é algo que não me assiste. :)